# String array being nullified when passing

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am having trouble passing a string array. Consider the following example code:

```
! -- Module to declare variable
module my_data
   implicit none

   ! -- Declare as deferred-length allocatable array
   character(len=:), dimension(:), allocatable :: str_array
end module my_data

! -- Module to call subroutine
module my_subs
   implicit none

contains
subroutine a(str_array)
   character(len=*), dimension(:), intent(IN) :: str_array
   integer :: i, j
   character :: c

   do i=1,size(str_array)
      do j=1,len_trim(str_array(i))
         c = str_array(i)(j:j)

         ! -- Write i, j, character, and int representation
         write(*,*) 'In call: ', i, j, ' "'//c//'", ichar = ', ichar(c)
      enddo
   enddo
end subroutine a
end module my_subs

! -- Main program
program main
   use my_data, only : str_array
   use my_subs, only : a
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: strlen = 200
   integer :: N, i, j
   character :: c

   ! -- Size of str array
   N = 2

   ! -- Allocate str_array, syntax from https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/287349
   allocate(character(strlen) :: str_array(N))

   ! -- Set both to the same string
   str_array = 'abc'

   do i=1,size(str_array)
      do j=1,len_trim(str_array(i))
         c = str_array(i)(j:j)

         ! -- Write i, j, character, and int representation
         write(*,*) 'In main: ', i, j, ' "'//c//'", ichar = ', ichar(c)
      enddo
   enddo

   call a(str_array)
end program main
```

The string array is declared as an array of assumed-length elements (from [the wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/strings#Recent_Extensions)). I allocate and set the values of the string (two elements, both to `abc` for this example). The main routine outputs full details about the string, then calls a subroutine which also outputs the (hopefully same) full details.

Using PGI, GCC, or Intel 15.0, I get the result I expect:

```
chaud106@ln0005 [~/Testing] % ifort --version && ifort -check all -warn all main.f90 && ./a.out
ifort (IFORT) 15.0.3 20150407
Copyright (C) 1985-2015 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 In main:            1           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In main:            1           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In main:            1           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In main:            2           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In main:            2           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In main:            2           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In call:            1           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In call:            1           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In call:            1           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In call:            2           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In call:            2           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In call:            2           3  "c", ichar =           99
```

However, Intel 18.0 sets the second element of the character array (all 3 characters) to the null character:

```
chaud106@ln0005 [~/Testing] % ifort --version && ifort -check all -warn all main.f90 && ./a.out
ifort (IFORT) 18.0.0 20170811
Copyright (C) 1985-2017 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 In main:            1           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In main:            1           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In main:            1           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In main:            2           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In main:            2           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In main:            2           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In call:            1           1  "a", ichar =           97
 In call:            1           2  "b", ichar =           98
 In call:            1           3  "c", ichar =           99
 In call:            2           1  "", ichar =            0
 In call:            2           2  "", ichar =            0
 In call:            2           3  "", ichar =            0
```

I have several questions related to this behavior:

1. Why is this occurring? I was thinking it could be related to Intel enforcing lhs-reallocation, but I'm not sure. Adding `-assume norealloc_lhs` didn't change anything.
2. What is the correct syntax to pass a string array like this? Could I declare it differently and avoid this problem?

The versions of Intel I have access to on this machine have the following behavior:

- ifort (IFORT) 15.0.2 20150121 - No nullification
- ifort (IFORT) 15.0.3 20150407 - No nullification
- ifort (IFORT) 16.0.3 20160415 - No nullification
- ifort (IFORT) 17.0.4 20170411 - Nullifies
- ifort (IFORT) 18.0.0 20170811 - Nullifies

On a different machine, I don't have any latest Intel:

- ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2 20140120 - No nullification
- ifort (IFORT) 16.0.0 20150815 - No nullification

Comment: Can you try with 18.0.3?

Comment: @francescalus not easily, no. I'll edit the question to include more specifics about the Intel versions I have access to on this machine.

Comment: @francescalus Based on the versions I have access to, the behavior occurs between versions 16.0.3 and 17.0.4 - almost a year. If anybody has access to versions between then, it might be good to test.

Comment: I have also posted this on the Intel Forums, as it seems to be specific to their compilers: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/783479

Comment: I answered the question, even though fixed in current release, partly because (no spoilers!) there are other compilers affected.  I won't reply to the Intel forum thread, but note that there _is_ required to be reallocation of `str_array` on assignment in the question's code.

Comment: Huh, interesting - I will keep an eye out for it on other compilers too. I will let the answers play out and continue to observe. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program works as expected with ifort 18.0.3.

I haven't tried with lots of previous versions, but I note that 17.0.1 was the point at which Fortran 2003 automatic allocation on intrinsic assignment became the default in that compiler.

The problematic line appears to be

```
str_array = 'abc'
```

Here, `str_array` should first be deallocated, because the right-hand side is an expression with different length parameter from the left-hand side.  Then it would be allocated as a character of length 3 (length of the right-hand side) and shape `[2]` as before (the right-hand side is scalar).  And that does happen, as can be seen with `SIZE(str_array)` and `LEN(str_array)`.  Something goes a little awry later on when using it as an actual argument, though.

There are ways to work around this problem with 18.0.1:

- give the dummy argument the `value` attribute;
- `str_array = ['abc','abc']` (previous allocation not required);
- `str_array(:) = 'abc'` (if you don't want the reallocation).

Many others likely available, depending on exactly what you need.  Upgrade your compiler to the latest version if you can, though.

Comment: You're correct that assignment using `str_array(:) = 'abc'` works, so I'll probably use that for now. How do I know which methods of assignment result in (re)allocation?

Comment: Also, it's then strange to me that including `assume -norealloc_lhs` at compile-time didn't help the Intel 18.0 behavior. Perhaps I will post on the Intel-specific forums and try to find out more about the part where "something goes a little awry later".

Comment: The "awry" part I would guess as the dope vector not being fully updated.  Loosely, deallocation happens before assignment when at least one of array shapes, length parameters, or dynamic types don't match.  And crucially, the LHS being allocatable (and in one case polymorphic).  `str_array(:)` isn't allocatable, so it remains the same shape and length.

Comment: -assume [no]realloc_lhs never affected allocatable deferred-length character assignment. That was only for array assignments as would have been valid in Fortran 90.

Comment: In this case, @SteveLionel, `str_array = 'abc'` is an array assignment that would be F90-valid, no?  But with (possible) different effect under F2003 rules.  Do you mean that option affects only those which are _in_valid under F90?

Comment: @francescalus , deferred-length character allocatables didn't exist in F90. The ifort realloc_lhs option applies only to reallocation of arrays with different shapes. The reallocation for characters with different lengths happens with the new syntax regardless. (The initial beta of where support for character(:) was introduced did tie this to realloc_lhs, but that was fixed before the release version.)

But in the case you have, 'abc' is a scalar so it expands to the same shape as str_array and there is no reallocationl But if shapes differ, it reallocates regardless of the option.

Comment: @SteveLionel, perhaps you're well placed to file a documentation bug report, then?  "Tells the compiler that when the left-hand side of an assignment is an allocatable object, it should be reallocated to the shape of the right-hand side of the assignment before the assignment occurs. This is the current Fortran Standard definition."

Comment: Oh, I thought I knew what you, @SteveLionel, meant, but now I'm confused.  Are you saying that in this case, under F2003+ rules, you don't expect `str_array='abc'` to result in reallocation of the LHS?  And that's why `[no]realloc_lhs` has no effect?  [I thought you meant in your first comment that `str_array='abc'` always results in reallocation in 17.0.1 even with `-assume norealloc_lhs`.]  Maybe we should delete our comments and start again?

Comment: What I meant was that for deferred-length character allocatables, ifort applies the current standard semantics and does reallocation (if required) no matter what you say for -assume realloc_lhs.